# Minimum bottleneck path between two vertices in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I have an undirected graph, where the value of the path is the maximum weight among all weights
edges included in it. And I want find the path of minimum value between two  given vertices in time $O(n + m)$, where $n$ - number of vertices, $m$ - number of edges.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem#Undirected_graphs

Answer (score 1):

I will use the fact that you can check for the connectivity between two vertices $s$ and $t$ in a graph with $m>0$ edges in time $O(m)$.

Call $G$ be the input graph, and let $s$ and $t$ be endpoints of the paths you are interested in. I will denote by $G_w$ (resp. $G^<_w$) the graph induced by all the edges of weight at most (resp. less than) $w$ in $G$. You can solve the problem using the following recursive algorithm:

If $G$ has no edges, report that $s$ and $t$ are disconnected in $G$.

If $G$ has at least one edge, find the median $w$ among the edge weights of $G$, and proceed as follows:

- If  $s$ and $t$ are connected in $G_w$ and disconnected in $G^<_w$, return $w$.
- If $s$ and $t$ are connected in both $G_w$ and $G^<_w$, apply the algorithm recursively on $G^<_w$ (notice that $G^<_w$ has at most $\frac{m}{2}$ edges).
- If $s$ and $t$ are disconnected in $G_w$, build the graph $G'$ obtained from $G$ by
  identifying all vertices that belong to the same connected component of $G_w$, and apply the algorithm recursively on $G'$ (notice that $G'$ has at most $\frac{m}{2}$ edges, since it can't contain any edge with weight less than or equal to $w$).

The time complexity of the above algorithm is described by the recurrence equation:
$T(m) = T(m/2) + O(m)$, which has solution $T(m)=O(m)$.

This problem is the same as its [maximization version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem) once all edge weights are multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: You can explain what the cases mean: "Otherwise", "If this is not the case"? How do these cases differ?

Comment: I explicitly stated the condition for each of the cases. Is this clear now?

Comment: Everything is clear, but what is the difference between $G_w$ and $G_w^{<}$

Comment: $G_w$ is the graph induced by all the edges of weight **at most** $w$ in $G$. $G^<_w$ is the graph induced by all the edges of weight **smaller than** $w$ in $G$. An edge of weight $w$ is in $G_w$ but not in $G^<_w$.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but we run the procedure twice at each stage, and the recurrence equality will be different.

Comment: There is only one recursive call at each stage, and a constant number of connectivity tests (at most $2$) that overall require linear time. This is captured by the $O(m)$ additive term in the recurrence.